# How to use the strncpy_s function from visual c++?

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-express

I am learning some new things in C++, and I was trying to test this strncpy_s function from Visual C++. However I am running into some problems as program crashes and I dunno whats going on but I am sure it is a pretty stupid problem. The source code is something like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    char *p;
    p=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen("Hello!\n"));
    strncpy_s(p,strlen("Hello!\n"),"Hello!\n",strlen("Hello!\n"));
    std::cout << p;
    std::cout << strlen("Hello!\n") << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

As I said I am not using std::string coz I want to try this new function and know how it works.

Comment: Use a debugger to see where the crash happens. Stackoverflow is not a debugger.

Comment: I did that. The problem was in strncpy_s function call.

Comment: I will copy the text i wrote in the question topic: "As I said I am not using std::string coz I want to try this new function and know how it works."

Comment: Yep. But what is the problem with std::cout << p;?

Comment: Also, in C++, there is no reason to use `strncpy` or almost any other function in the `cstring` header.

Comment: As I said, I wanted to try this new function, I am looking forward to learning new stuff.

Comment: @Victor: p is a pointer, you don't want to output the pointer, you want to output the string that it points to. Try `std::cout << &p;`

Comment: @Nic: I think you got that backwards... that part of his code is fine, but your replacement prints the pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take my comments back, I read [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5dae5d43%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) more carefully.  Your code is passing invalid parameters, and is invoking the invalid parameter handler.  Maybe that's what's happening.  Namely:

```
p=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen("Hello!\n"));
```

This line allocates room for 7 characters, which is the length of the string, but *not enough room for a null terminator*.  (This is generally an error)

The documentation for `strncpy_s` says: These functions try to copy the first D characters of strSource to strDest, where D is the lesser of count and the length of strSource. **If those D characters will fit** within strDest (whose size is given as numberOfElements) **and still leave room for a null terminator**, then those characters are copied and a terminating null is appended; **otherwise, strDest[0] is set to the null character and the invalid parameter handler is invoked**, as described in Parameter Validation.

Are you possibly seeing the "invalid parameter handler"?

Comment: true, there should be a +1 there.

Answer (score 2):

You need 1 more character for terminating character (`'\0'`) so you need to replace `strlen("Hello!\n")` with `strlen("Hello!\n") + 1`. You could store this length in some variable instead of calling `strlen` again. Also since you are using C++ you could use `new / delete` instead of `malloc / free`:

```
int len = strlen("Hello!\n") + 1;
char *p;
p = new char[len];
strncpy_s(p, len, "Hello!\n", len);
std::cout << p << len << std::endl;
delete[] p;
```

Comment: You could also avoid a run-time length calculation using `sizeof "Hello!\n"` rather than `strlen("Hello!\n")+1`. That only works for string literals, of course.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Good note. But I think that `strlen` is more "illustrative" in this case since it was the main cause of his problem.

Answer (score 2):

The 'security-enhanced' string functions are essentially designed to crash if they run into a problem.

From [Microsoft's docs on `strncpy_s()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5dae5d43.aspx):

> These functions try to copy the first D characters of strSource to
>   strDest, where D is the lesser of count and the length of strSource.
>   If those D characters will fit within strDest (whose size is given as
>   numberOfElements) and still leave room for a null terminator, then
>   those characters are copied and a terminating null is appended;
>   otherwise, strDest[0] is set to the null character and the invalid
>   parameter handler is invoked, as described in Parameter Validation.
>
> There is an exception to the above paragraph. If count is _TRUNCATE,
>   then as much of strSource as will fit into strDest is copied while
>   still leaving room for the terminating null which is always appended.

The [description of the Paramter Validation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ksazx244.aspx) is:

> The behavior of the C Runtime when an invalid parameter is found is to
>   call the currently assigned invalid parameter handler. The default
>   invalid parameter invokes Watson crash reporting, which causes the
>   application to crash and asks the user if they want to load the crash
>   dump to Microsoft for analysis. In Debug mode, an invalid parameter
>   also results in a failed assertion.
>
> This behavior can be changed by using the function
>   _set_invalid_parameter_handler to set the invalid parameter handler to your own function. ...

Your example program provides a buffer that is too small by one `char` (there's no room for the null terminator).

So unless you specifically change what should happen when the `strxxxx_s` functions do when an error is encountered, your program will crash by design.  The idea is that a crash is better than a bug that may open a security hole.

Comment: If "a crash is better than a bug that may open a security hole" than the exploit of such bug will cause Denial Of Service. Denial Of Service is a security problem either, so this function isn't actually that safe.

Comment: @Victor: I'm not saying that it fixes all security bugs. I'm not even giving an opinion here about whether the design makes sense. Microsoft's default behavior here is 'implementation defined' accordiing to the TR-24731 (is this stuff in C11? I need to read up on that...). I suppose MS believes that an in-your-face crash is preferable to a silent security hole. Also note that the design does allow to avoid the crash if you want to put in the effort to do so. You may want to read the rationale: http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1173.pdf

Comment: Ok Michael Burr, thanks. I am not used to read languages specification documents, maybe I should change that.

Answer (score 1):

`strlen(s)` will only tell you the length of the string without the NUL terminator. To allocate space into which to copy a string, you normally use `strlen(s)+1`, to add space for a NUL terminator.

Comment: I must be very stupid, I couldn't realize that, simple stuff.

Comment: @Victor: Anybody who hasn't made that mistake at least once probably isn't a C programmer. The time it get ugly is when you accidentally do: `strlen(s+1)`, which still compiles, but gives a wrong answer (too small by 2 instead of 1) but the mistake is even easier to miss.

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate strlen("Hello!\n") + 1 (for the null terminator).  And sizeof(char) is utterly pointless since sizeof(char) is guaranteed to be 1 on all platforms.

Comment: I like the sizeof operator, that's why i did sizeof(char), its just that cool.

Comment: Code that serves no purpose isn't cool.  It just adds complexity.

Comment: May be someone will came up with a machine where sizeof(char)==4? ;)

Comment: Not in C++ they can't, @Victor. C++ *defines* `char` to have size 1. In fact, `sizeof` returns the number of chars.

Comment: Dude, I was joking when I said "someone will came up with a machine where sizeof(char)==4? ;)". This emoticon ;) means "joking". If u really feel annoyed by that sizeof(char) then I will never do it again just to see you happy ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using malloc or char* if you're using C++?

```
std::string p = "Hello!\n";
std::cout << p;
std::cout << p.length();
```

or

```
std::string* p = new std::string("Hello!\n");
std::cout << p;
std::cout << p->length();
```

But to answer your original question you probably need to use `strlen(p) + 1`

And if you need a char* from your string you can use `p.c_str()`

Comment: As I said in the topic I was trying to learn this new function, that's why I did not used std::string.

Comment: @Victor: My apologies, I missed that comment after the code block.